# How to convert an S4 class objects slots into vectors or matrix?

Tags: r, r-s4

I have an s4 class object from ROCR package. It has several slots containing data that are related among each other (i.e. "x.values", "y.values", and "alpha.values").

I would like to merge them in a matrix by accessing the slots to make some calculations (Youden indices, etc.)

I've tried things like this (according to my limited knowledge of R)

```
test<-cbind(perf@x.values,perf@y.values,perf@alpha.values)
```

and other formulas such as changing the class of the object directly...

but anything worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the slot names (use `getClass` if you don't), you can pull them out with the `@` operator. I don't know ROCR but assuming you have the slot names right, you can do

```
x <- perf@x.values
y <- perf@y.values
a <- perf@alpha.values
```

and then examine them like any other R object. Your cbind probably isn't working because the dimensions of the objects don't match.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The dimensions are the same but the result seems to mantain the slot format... Finally I applied unlist to the object x<-unlist and it works!